# Creating a symbolic link in Yocto recipe based on DISTRO_FEATURES variable

Tags: yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe

In yocto recipe after generating binary i want to  create symbolic link

var = ${@bb.utils.contains('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'TEMP', 'temp1', 'temp2', d)}

if var is temp1 i want to create symbolic link x is main bin

i tried adding task

```
do_addlink() {
  if [ "${var}" = "temp1" ]; then
    ln -rsf ${bindir}/x ${bindir}/y
  fi
}
addtask addlink before do_package after do_compile
```

but it's not creating symbolic link

Comment: The second argument of the ln command should point to ${D} destination, where the link should be actually created: `ln -rsf ${bindir}/x ${D}${bindir}/y`

Comment: yeah i tried this but it's not creating link

Comment: Hvae you added `TEMP` to `DISTRO_FEATURES` also?

Answer (score -1):

It's a path issue; by just prepending the ${D} variable to the paths into the symlink, it will make the symlink from and into the "image" directory of that recipe, and later Yocto will pick the files for the rootfs.

```bash
ln -rsf ${D}/${bindir}/x ${D}/${bindir}/y
```

Also, you would want your task to be created after the `do_install` task: `addtask addlink before do_package after do_install`

---

Furthermore, consider using the new distro feature in lowercase letters, as it aligns with the standard convention used for such features. Additionally, I recommend utilizing a custom variable instead of DISTRO_FEATURES for your specific purpose. The term "distro feature" typically implies more significant modifications at the distribution level, such as adopting a different Init System like Systemd instead of SysVInit. Also a motivation to not change the distro feature variable in this case, is that by modifying it your build process will initiate from a stage that closely resembles starting from scratch.